# How can I get a /dev/ptp0 ptp hardware clock on a VM running Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, vmware-player, ptp

I'm trying to run software which needs to get hardware timestamps using ptp. Therefore, I need to have **/dev/ptp0** available. I'm running Linux/Ubuntu on a VMWare.

Is there a way to make this work on a VM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

in short: **ptp_kvm.ko**

```
# modprobe ptp_kvm
# ls /dev/ptp*
/dev/ptp0  /dev/ptp_kvm
```

in long:

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.5 and later provide a virtual PTP hardware clock (PHC), which enables the guests to synchronize to the host with a sub-microsecond accuracy.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/virtualization_deployment_and_administration_guide/chap-kvm_guest_timing_management#sect-KVM_guest_timing_management-Host-guest-time-sync (subscription-wall?)

To enable the PHC device, do the following **inside a virtual machine**:

Set the ptp_kvm module to load after reboot.

```
# echo ptp_kvm > /etc/modules-load.d/ptp_kvm.conf
```

Add the /dev/ptp0 clock as a reference to the chrony configuration:

```
# echo "refclock PHC /dev/ptp0 poll 2" >> /etc/chrony.conf
```

Restart the chrony daemon:

```
# systemctl restart chronyd
```

To verify the host-guest time synchronization has been configured correctly, use the `chronyc sources` command on a guest.

```
# chronyc sources
#* PHC0                          0   2   377     4     -6ns[   -6ns] +/-  726ns
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer VMware doesn't support linuxptp emulating ptp devices.
Closest thing is 
find this on [this website](https://www.shigemk2.com/entry/2014/05/22/Precision_Time_Protocol_on_Linux%3A_Introduction_to_linuxptp_%23linuxcon)

> FYI Running linuxptp on qemu-kvm
>
> Run two virtual machines for GM and Slave and use recent Fedora, RHEL 6.5 7.0
>      Use virtual NIC emulationg e10000 (supports software timestamping)
>      don't forget to define appropriate firewall rules to allow multi-cast
>      dont' expect high precision and accuracy

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there no way to emulate the ptp hardware clock? I need it only for testing my application. Or is there any other way to get hardware timestamps?

Comment: never tried this but you can give [this](https://github.com/mlichvar/clknetsim) a try. it git repo simulating clock. may help. let me know i it worked.

Comment: So thank you! I'm still trying to understand what it does...is it simulating a ptp hardware clock? Because this is what I would need...

Answer (score 2):

It's now 2021, and I found out that if you're able to compile your own Linux Kernel, there is a built-in driver already. Enable it with `make menuconfig`:

```
Device Drivers --> PTP clock support --> KVM virtual PTP clock
```

Inside a KVM guest, a new `/dev/ptp0` device will appear, as well as the following Kernel boot log:

```
pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
PTP clock support registered
```